# Are off-brand framing nails compatible with my Craftsman nailer?

Tags: tools, powertools, nails

I have a Craftsman Clipped Head Angle Framing Nailer (28 degrees) Model No. 351.181790.

They don't appear to stock the specific nails for this gun anymore. Which according to the [manual](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/494487/Craftsman-351-181790.html#manual) are:

- 18351 - 8 penny, .120 2 1/2"
- 18352 - 10 penny, .120 3"
- 18353 - 16 penny, .120 3 1/2"
- 18357 - Galvanized 8 penny, .120 2 1/2"
- 18358 - Galvanized 10 penny, .120 3"
- 18359 - Galvanized 16 penny, .120 3 1/2"

When I search for those nails I just get out of stock pages from Sears. I did find one [forum](http://www.shopyourway.com/questions/1186505) that claimed:

> I am sorry that we do not stock these nails any longer but you should be able to get them from any big box hardware stores or home centers.
>   Stanley Bostitch will fit.
>   Campbell Housfeld will fit.
>   Atro nails will fit.

**Do any of these other brand nails work with my Craftsman?**

Comment: This is a hard question to answer for sure without the actual gun in my hand at the store.  I've searched online for 20 minutes now and most places says you can just use the right gauge, length, and angle nails.  +1 for your problem and research.

Comment: Just make sure you match the angle, the clipped head part, and the collation (paper/plastic/wire). With that, you should be fine.

Comment: I found that my Ryobi nailer worked with any brand as long as the gauge was correct.  (Which I inexpertly tested by trying to use the wrong gauge).

Comment: Generally, guns will take any reputable brand of nails as long as they are the same spec.  If a gun has a problem with any nails but OEM, I would expect there to be customer feedback about that online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just keep an eye on the angle and you should be fine. If you're really concerned bring the gun to a store with you and check a strip to see if it looks like it will fit okay. I'm sure you can return the box if there are issues.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy them from a very popular internet merchant: [Stanley Bostich .120 28°](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000B9RUMG)

Comment: That link says 'Full Head' frame nail. Is that not different from clipped head?

Comment: You are so right my friend, my apologies. The same merchant does carry the clipped head: http://www.amazon.com/BOSTITCH-S10D-FH-Clipped-120-Inch-Collated/dp/B0002SP85C

Comment: Those are wire collated, shouldn't they be paper collated?